# How to encapsulate / wrap a VueJS component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**Hi everybody, please pardon my english :-)**

I have a Vue component that can take dynamic slots (the names of the slots will depend on a props).

I use it on several places and some of the slots are always present.

To avoid redundancy, I'm looking for a way to create a component that "wrap" the final component to allow me to define only the additionals slots.

If there is an "obvious" way to achieve it, I may have missed it :-)

### Code example

#### Without a "wrap component"

```
<b-table
  show-empty
  small
  hover
  
  [...some others and always present props...]

  :items="aDataVarThatWillChangeBasedOnTheContext"

  [...some others and uniq props...]
>
  <template slot="same-1">
   A slot that will always be present with the same content (for example, a checkbox in the first column)
  </template>

  <template slot="same-2">
   A slot that will always be present with the same content (for example, some action buttons in the last column)
  </template>

  [...some others and always present slots...]
  
  <template slot="not-the-same">
   A slot that is only used in this context (for example, a duration based on a row timestamp and a timestamp picked by the user)
  </template>

  [...some others and uniq slots...]
</b-table>
```

#### With a "wrap component"

```
<my-b-table
  :items="aDataVarThatWillChangeBasedOnTheContext"
>
  <template slot="not-the-same">
   A slot that is only used in this context (for example, a duration based on a row timestamp and a timestamp picked by the user)
  </template>
</my-b-table>
```

Note: The dynamic slot name is not predictible.
If I suddenly need a "foo" column, I should be able to pass a "foo" slot (and a "HEAD_foo" slot, in my case)

### Some researches

I read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) that:

> They’re (the functionnal components) also very useful as wrapper components. For example, when you need to:
>
> - Programmatically choose one of several other components to delegate to
> - Manipulate children, props, or data before passing them on to a child component

And "Manipulate children, props, or data before passing them on to a child component" seems to be exactly what I need.

I looked on render function but a lot of things seems to be not implemented, like the v-model, and I have difficulties to figure out how to pass dynamic slots...

**Thank you in advance for your(s) answer(s) !**

up: At the 07.03.2018 I still dont have any idea about how to solve this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer that was somehow unclear to me that month ago.

("Dynamic" means here "not explicitely declared by the component, but gived by the parent")

### Wrapper component

Props and scoped slots can be gived dynamically by the `options` object of `createElement` function.

"Simple" Slots can be gived dynamically by the `childs` array of `createElement` function.

### Wrapped component

Props can't be dynamic unless the component is functional.

Slots can always be retrieved dynamically.

Scoped slots can be retrieved only if the component isn't functional.

### Conclusion

It's not possible to have dynamics props and scoped slots at the same time...

But it's possible to declare all the needed props and then to use a "non-functionnal" component as wrapper and as wrapped.

---

## How to

### Retrieve from non-functional component

```js
var component = Vue.component('component-name', {
  props: ['name', 'of', 'the', 'props'],
  
  // [...]
  
  aMethod: function () {
    this._props // all the declared props
    this.$slots // all the slots
    this.$scopedSlots // all the scoped slots
  }
});
```

### Retrieve from functional component

```js
var component = Vue.component('component-name', {
  functional: true,

  render: function (createElement, context) {
    context.props // all the props
    context.children // all the slots as an array
    context.slots() // all the slots as an object
  }
});
```

### Give to child component

```js
var component = Vue.component('component-name', {
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(
      childComponent,
      {
        props: propsToGive,
        scopedSlots: scopedSlotsToGive
      },
      [
        // non-scoped slots to give
        createElement('slot-tag-name', {slot: 'slot-name'})
      ]
    );
  }
});
```

---

## References

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components

---

## Sandbox

https://jsfiddle.net/5umk7p52/

Answer (score 0):

Just make a regular component out of your customized `<b-table>`.

You'll need to define an `items` prop for your component to pass as the `items` for the `<b-table>` component.

And, to define a `slot` for your component, you'll need to use the `<slot>` tag, specifying the name using the `name` attribute.

If you'd like to make one of the slots from the `<b-table>` component accessible in the `<my-b-table>` component, simply pass a `<slot>` tag as the content of the slot in your custom component.

It would look something like this:

```
Vue.component('my-b-table', {
  template: `
    <b-table
      show-empty
      small
      hover
      :items="items"  
    >
      <template slot="same-1">
        Content to pass to the b-table's slot
      </template>

      <slot name="not-the-same">
        A slot that is only used in this context
      </slot>

      <template slot="last_edit">
        <slot name="last_edit">
          A slot to pass content to the b-table component's slot
        </slot>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  `,
  props: { items: Array },
});
```

Comment: It's sadly not so simple: With the b-table component you can use a slot for displaying a particular column in a particular way.

For example: If you have a column named "last_edit", you can use a slot like this:
```
<template slot="last_edit">
  <!-- custom HTML / JS / ... display for the "last_edit" cells -->
</template>
```

As it's a "dynamic" slot, I would like to "give" them to the b-table child component

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You mean you want that slot to be in your `<my-b-table>` component as well?

Comment: Yeah, I need to be able to give a slot to the b-table *through* my-b-table

Comment: The difficulty is that I dont know in advence the slot name to pass through the my-b-table component as they will be different in every usages:

`<template slot="<I-dont-know-for-now>">
  <slot name="<I-dont-know-for-now>">
    A slot to pass content to the b-table component's slot
  </slot>
</template>`

Maybe the books page will display a date, and the articles page will display a price, both "page component" should be able to use my-b-table to avoid redundancy to display checkboxes, ids, and others identicals fields and both should be able to describe how to handle specific fields

Comment: Can you please add all of your requirements as an edit to your question and I'll try to see if I can come up with a different answer?

Comment: Done, tell me if it's still unclear...

...and thank you for your time !